# The splitting field of $x^7 - 2$ and its Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This question is more or less a "is it me or is it something wrong in the answer sheet"-question. In one of the previous exam sheets at my university, I am supposed to find the order of the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^7 -2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I found it very confusing that the answer sheet meant that the order of this group was 42 and not 49. I first considered $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[7]{2}]}$ as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I felt convinced that since the $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[7]{2}]}$ has 7 linear independent basis elements, $[\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[7]{2}]} : \mathbb{Q}] = 7$. More or less the same argument goes for $\mathbb{Q[\omega]}$, so that I would get that $[\mathbb{Q[\sqrt[7]{2},\omega]}:\mathbb{Q}] = 49$.

If the answer sheet is correct, then it would imply from my understanding that there must exist a subgroup of the Galois group which has 2 elements, which makes no sense to me.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: The degree of a nontrivial $7$th root of unity over $\mathbf Q$ is *not* $7$, but $6$.  Since $[\mathbf Q(\sqrt[7]{2}):\mathbf Q] = 7$, which is relatively prime to $6$, the degree of a nontrivial $7$th root of unity over $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[7]{2})$ is also $6$.  The answer sheet was not wrong. You are also making a bad deduction that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same degree $m$ over $\mathbf Q$ then $\mathbf Q(\alpha,\beta)$ has degree $m^2$ over $\mathbf Q$. That is just false in general (but it's also not pertinent to your situation if it is done correctly).

Comment: Ah, yes of course, I realized it now. Thanks.

Comment: And the usual complex conjugation gives you that subgroup with 2 elements. When restricted to the splitting field.